# How to get a filepath from a directory without file name in iOS Objective c

Tags: objective-c

Good day

How do you get a filePath without fileName from a fullpath.
Lets say I have a path:

NSString *myPath = @"/Users/myName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/.../Library/Caches/Getting Started.pdf";

and I want to just have

NSString *newPath = @"/Users/myName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/.../Library/Caches";

I didnt want to substring it, I hope there is a better solution.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Check the class reference for `NSString`.

```
newPath = [path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
```

Comment: this is exactly what Ive been looking for. You are a genius . Thanks a lot @Avi

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
  NSString *documentPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

    NSLog(@" DocumentPath %@",documentPath);
```